# Softlayer Python API cannot retrieve IP for long time

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a Python API script I have used for two years. It works everytime. In the past two years, once in awhile, it will take more than a minute to obtain an IP address.

However, the past two weeks, the retrieval of IP can take 20 minutes up to three hours to retrieve an IP. This is the message I get while it tries until it get it. I created a ticket but, they asked me to ask here.

INFO:root:No IP for indusmotors yet. Waiting before retry
INFO:SoftLayer.transports:POST https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

Here is the relevant code. I apss in the parameters and wait for the IP.

## #

## Creates a new CCI based on the input options dict

## #

def createImagesFromTemplate(inputDict, verify, client):
    # grab a session with the vs manager client
    mgr = SoftLayer.VSManager(client)

```
try:
    if (verify):
        logging.info("Verifying Input Options")
        vsi = mgr.verify_create_instances(inputDict)
        logging.info("Verify Response was: ")
        pp(resp)
    else: #we create for real
        #logging.info("Creating image for %s  from Template ID: %s", input_options['hostname'], input_options['image_id'])
        #mgr.create_instances(input)
        vsi = mgr.create_instances(inputDict)
        if vsi:
            print("The list has been submitted")
        else:
            print("An error has occurred in the submission")

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    logging.info("CCI Create request failed")
    logging.info("SoftLayerAPIError occurred faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

## #

## Waits until there is an IP address in a specified CCI and the retrieves and returns it

## #

def getIpFromVs(inst_id, client):
    #get the IP Address from the cci managers extension
    mgr = SoftLayer.VSManager(client)
    vsi = mgr.get_instance(inst_id)

```
get_ip = '' #No IP yet
# wait until we get an ip address... should be anytime now
while ('primaryIpAddress' not in vsi):
    logging.info("No IP for %s yet. Waiting before retry" % vsi['hostname'])
    time.sleep(20)
    vsi =  mgr.get_instance(inst_id)

while (vsi['primaryIpAddress'] == '' ):
    logging.info("Still no IP for %s yet. Waiting before retry" % vsi['hostname'])
    time.sleep(5)
    vsi =  mgr.get_instance(inst_id)

get_ip = vsi['primaryIpAddress']
return get_ip
```

The request was usually without having to do a retry. Was there a change?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new CCI it has to be approved and then the provisioned process begins, once the provisioned process has been completed your machine will be power on and you will able to get the IP address information.

The issue that you are facing is most likely due to:
1.- Your CCI was not approved, this must be performed automatically by Softlayer, but sometimes something could went wrong, so an Softlayer’s employee has to approve manually your order.
2.-The provisioning process is taking more time that the expected. Sometimes the provisioning have issues and a Softlayer's employee has to review what went wrong and fix it.

Those kind of delays in the provisioning could be the root of the issue that are you facing. I recommend you before verifying if that the IP is available you must review if the CCI has been provisioned. See this code for that:

```
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username= "arst"
    api_key = "1234arst"
) 

object_mask = 'mask.provisionDate'

cci = client['Virtual_Guest'].getObject(mask=object_mask)

if ( 'provisionDate' in cci and cci['provisionDate'] != ):
    print 'CCI %s is online' % cci['hostname']
else:
    print 'CCI %s is provisioning' % cci['hostname']
```

See more information here: http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/simplified-cci-creation

Regards

Comment: This script has run for two years with the above code. Every once in a great while, it could not obtain an IP for maybe 5 minutes. 99% of the time, it would be complete within a minute. Now, most of the time it takes between 20 minutes and hours. I have not seen this when doing it via the ui.

I will implement your code.A couple of times, the device has been provisioned and the IP comes later. Most of the time, after the ip address is obtained, the provisioning is immediate. Thank you for the help.